# upgraded WYGWAM 3.3.3 - config icons not right

Tags: wygwam, wysiwyg, config

When I go into the toolbar config this icon http://d.pr/i/3UIj is used for inserting an image.

No console errors. When I look at the actual publish page, everything is as expected.

Tried clearing the cache to no avail.

Anyone seen similar?

Comment: Have you deleted and re-uploaded your `/themes/third_party/wygwam` directory?

Comment: yup, tried that

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after updating Wygwam from 3.2.2 to 3.3.3 on EE 2.7.3.  I found that it's a browser cache issue.  After clearing out the cache, the icons were back.